# Re-instantiate jQuery ui accordion on dom modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a jQuery UI accordion on my check out page which works fine when you first visit the page, but I have a *Login* link which uses ajax to switch part of the page to a login box and on that page I have a link that ajax's back to the original page, once back on the original page the accordion stops functioning.

1. Click "BUY A LICENSE"
2. Click any ADD TO CART button
3. Click CHECKOUT

On the check out page you'll see the accordion "Create An Account (Optional)" works fine, then click on "Already have a RockItPro.com account? Login", then click on "Need to create an account? Register or checkout as a guest." You'll notice the accordion isn't functioning once back on the original page.

**jQuery ui accordion code:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$( ".accordion2" ).accordion({
animate: 500,
collapsible: true,
active: false,
heightStyle: 'content' });
});
```

**The code for the accordion:**

```
<div class="accordion2">
    <h3 class="faqaccordion">Create An Account (optional)</h3>
    <div>
    <fieldset id="edd_register_account_fields">
            <span><legend><?php _e( 'Create An Account (optional)', 'edd' ); if( !edd_no_guest_checkout() ) ?></legend></span>
            <br/><span class="createaccount-description"><?php _e( 'Create an optional account to re-download purchases, view past orders, and download beats for non-profit use.', 'edd' ); ?></span>
            <?php echo do_shortcode('[userpro_social_connect size="medium" width="295px" facebook_title="Sign Up with Facebook" twitter_title="Sign Up with Twitter" google_title="Sign Up with Google+"]'); ?>
            <span class="login-or"><h3><span>OR</span></h3></span>
            <?php do_action('edd_register_account_fields_before'); ?>
            <p id="edd-user-login-wrap">
                <label for="edd_user_login">
                    <?php _e( 'Username', 'edd' ); ?>
                    <?php if( edd_no_guest_checkout() ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </label>
                <input name="edd_user_login" id="edd_user_login" class="<?php if(edd_no_guest_checkout()) { echo 'required '; } ?>edd-input" type="text" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Username', 'edd' ); ?>" title="<?php _e( 'Username', 'edd' ); ?>"/>
            </p>
            <p id="edd-user-pass-wrap">
                <label for="password">
                    <?php _e( 'Password', 'edd' ); ?>
                    <?php if( edd_no_guest_checkout() ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </label>
                <input name="edd_user_pass" id="edd_user_pass" class="<?php if(edd_no_guest_checkout()) { echo 'required '; } ?>edd-input" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Password', 'edd' ); ?>" type="password"/>
            </p>
            <p id="edd-user-pass-confirm-wrap" class="edd_register_password">
                <label for="password_again">
                    <?php _e( 'Password Again', 'edd' ); ?>
                    <?php if( edd_no_guest_checkout() ) { ?>
                    <span class="edd-required-indicator">*</span>
                    <?php } ?>
                </label>
                <input name="edd_user_pass_confirm" id="edd_user_pass_confirm" class="<?php if(edd_no_guest_checkout()) { echo 'required '; } ?>edd-input" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Confirm password', 'edd' ); ?>" type="password"/>
            </p>
            <?php do_action( 'edd_register_account_fields_after' ); ?>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You apply the accordion plugin only to the DOM elements matched at the time when calling the function. When you later AJAX-in new elements, you need to re-apply. Just do so in the AJAX's done callback.

Comment: I dont understand flow . please give us more details

Answer (score 0):

You should do
    $('class_contaier').on('click','.accordion2', function (){
      $(this).accordion ({....});
     }
    );

Edit------
It might be $('.accordion2') instead of $(this).